# Как определить номер позиции текущего элемента вывода view Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, view

Здравствуйте! кто может подсказать как мне определить номер позиции текущего элемента модуля view Drupal 7, Блок с выводом короткого описания фильмов находится на главной, при нажатии кнопки "Просмотр" идет переход на страницу фильма нода (оно же оформлено как каталог с помощью модуля Views navigation)  и мне нужно сделать такую навигацию[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на данный момент у меня есть такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и там идёт еще ссылка и там указана позиция

*/node/26?**position=2**&list=hQSUKre1d2I73nKmx2JSyYKm8CnfnWxXmJ9gmAAbdXY* (выделено жирным)

может как-то можно от туда ее достать, или есть болие адекватный способ...? P.S В настройках самого модуля и въюшки нету нумерации (по крайней мере не видел)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ... Спасибо)

Comment: Думаю тут надо править в коде модуля.. А вы пробовали задать вопрос на drupal.stackexchange.com?

Comment: нет, я даже не знал что есть такое) спасибо)